# Merge rows in 1 df by ID and create new columns of differing data in R (in very large df)

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, reshape

I have some duplicate IDs in my df, but I want only 1 row per ID. I cannot use `unique()` or `distinct()` because then some data would be erased, as the rows are not identical.

Please see this example:

```
# The style of df I have 
df <- data.frame(IDs=c(1,1,2,3,4,4,4,5),
                 Intervention=c("Progesterone", "Stitch", NA, "Stitch", "Progesterone", "Stitch", "Pessary", "Progesterone"),
                 Other_data1= c(22,22,32,44,24,24,24,NA), 
                 Other_data2=c("a","a","b","c","d","d","d","e"))
df
#   IDs Intervention Other_data1 Other_data2
# 1   1 Progesterone          22           a
# 2   1       Stitch          22           a
# 3   2         <NA>          32           b
# 4   3       Stitch          44           c
# 5   4 Progesterone          24           d
# 6   4       Stitch          24           d
# 7   4      Pessary          24           d
# 8   5 Progesterone          NA           e
```

So if I used `unique()` I would lose the full information in the `df$Intervention` column.

Please could someone let me know how I can get the df into this format:

```
# The style of df I want
df_I_want <- data.frame(IDs=c(1,2,3,4,5),
                        Progesterone=c("Yes", NA, "No", "Yes", "Yes"),
                        Stitch=c("Yes", NA, "Yes", "Yes", "No"),
                        Pessary=c("No", NA, "No", "Yes", "No"),
                        Other_data1= c(22,32,44,24,NA), 
                        Other_data2=c("a","b","c","d","e"))
df_I_want
#   IDs Progesterone Stitch Pessary Other_data1 Other_data2
# 1   1          Yes    Yes      No          22           a
# 2   2         <NA>   <NA>    <NA>          32           b
# 3   3           No    Yes      No          44           c
# 4   4          Yes    Yes     Yes          24           d
# 5   5          Yes     No      No          NA           e
```

My real df contains thousands of rows x hundreds of columns, so I have many cases of `df$Other_data` so I cannot really manually type out excluding these rows when reshaping the df. But there is only 1 column where the data differs by the row, as in the above example with `df$Intervention`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another `pivot_wider` solution, but here I use `mutate` and `case_when` to identify their corresponding values under the newly expanded columns.

If all of the three newly expanded columns are `NA`, they should remain `NA`. Otherwise, treat `NA` as "No" and non-`NA` as "Yes".

Note that within `across()`, you should input the column position (or column names) of the newly expanded columns (e.g. `Progesterone`, `Stitch` and  `Pessary` are newly created, and they are in position 4 to 6, therefore `4:6`).

**Edit:** Added `length(unique(na.omit(df$Intervention)))` when calculating and comparing the number of `NA`s across the newly expanded columns so that it's more dynamic

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Intervention, values_from = Intervention) %>% 
  select(-"NA") %>% 
  mutate(across(4:6, ~case_when(rowSums(is.na(across(4:6))) == length(unique(na.omit(df$Intervention))) ~ NA_character_,
                                is.na(.x) ~ "No",
                                !is.na(.x) ~ "Yes")))

# A tibble: 5 × 6
    IDs Other_data1 Other_data2 Progesterone Stitch Pessary
  <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>       <chr>        <chr>  <chr>  
1     1          22 a           Yes          Yes    No     
2     2          32 b           NA           NA     NA     
3     3          44 c           No           Yes    No     
4     4          24 d           Yes          Yes    Yes    
5     5          NA e           Yes          No     No
```

Comment: I ticked this as the correct answer as you preserved the NAs in ID 2. Thank you for the well-explained code

Answer (score 1):

**Updated:** I have now updated the code so that you have "Yes" and "No" for each intervention.

You can use the function `pivot_wider()` to achieve this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(IDs=c(1,1,2,3,4,4,4,5),
                 Intervention=c("Progesterone", "Stitch", NA, "Stitch", "Progesterone", "Stitch", "Pessary", "Progesterone"),
                 Other_data1= c(22,22,32,44,24,24,24,NA), 
                 Other_data2=c("a","a","b","c","d","d","d","e"))

df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Intervention, 
              values_from = Intervention) %>%
  select(-c(`NA`)) %>%
  mutate(across(.cols = Progesterone:Pessary, 
                .fns = ~case_when(is.na(.) ~ "No",
                                  TRUE ~ "Yes")))
#> # A tibble: 5 × 6
#>     IDs Other_data1 Other_data2 Progesterone Stitch Pessary
#>   <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>       <chr>        <chr>  <chr>  
#> 1     1          22 a           Yes          Yes    No     
#> 2     2          32 b           No           No     No     
#> 3     3          44 c           No           Yes    No     
#> 4     4          24 d           Yes          Yes    Yes    
#> 5     5          NA e           Yes          No     No
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>